# Disable confirm dialog when passing credentials in URL for Basic Auth

Tags: firefox, dialog, basic-authentication, confirmation

is there a config option to disable this;

[image: firefox confirm dialog]

dialog when visiting a URL and passing credentials in the URL, e.g.

```
https://user:password@protected-site.com/
```

Comment: is this at all relevant, http://superuser.com/questions/664656/how-to-configure-firefox-for-ntlm-sso-single-sign-on

Comment: @francium: I tried that, did not work. See my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the somewhat hidden `network.http.phishy-userpass-length` to `1024` fixed it.

```
user_pref("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 1024);
```

See http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=156433 for more information.